# Google drive, onedrive or box which is the fastest API method for displaying complete folder contents?

Tags: codeigniter, heroku, google-drive-api, box-api, onedrive

We are working on a web application for photo selections/proofing. To manage the photo albums, we want to use a file sharing service like dropbox, google drive, onedrive etc.

One of our use cases includes displaying albums with large quantity of photos inside our web application. We are currently using dropbox to fetch complete folders (albums) but since the dropbox api doesn't offer batch requests, it takes A LOT of time to generate individual share links and display inside our application (in terms of hours)

I am personally checking other APIs too but will really appreciate little guidance from people having experience with other APIs like google drive, onedrive, box.com etc

What will be the best method/api to achieve the use case efficiently?

Like I personally think if we have a batch operations available, we would be able to fetch an album of 3000 photos (120 kb avg size) in less than 5 minutes on a normal internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All services you mention (dropbox, onedrive, google drive) offer a thumbnail service. My advice is to use that functionality first.
So (supported by all services):

- request meta data about all files in folder (one call), including thumbnail URL and id. Normally this request is paged. For 3000 images you need only three requests (if page-size is 1000, the maximum for Google Drive API)
- display thumbnails (using the cached URL)
- retrieve actual image if user selects thumbnail based on the cached id. Which is one call

We integrated with all three services (and s3) and in my experience, the performance is more than enough for this kind of scenario.

Comment: It's a good advice. We will switch to this flow if we don't find any other methods. The problem I foresee in this technique is that we are using full res image in light box for selection with a checkbox to mark it selected. So it's very easy pressing the right arrow key and checking the box for selected photos. The images will give a little lag in loading in the lightbox with this technique. Nevertheless it still is a good option if we don't find any other solution.

Comment: We are using a not-very-reliable method right now to load all images inside our application. Biggest of the albums have load times less than 5 minutes and selection process is very fast for the users (they can quickly scroll through all the images on arrow keys). Only issue is that we want to switch to a reliable API for stability. If any API provides fetching URLs for full resolution images in a folder with single call, our problem will be solved.

Comment: See my updated answer.  I see you are new here. Welcome! BTW if this is good advice, you need to up vote / accept answer. That is how SO works :)

Comment: We will try this method. Thank you. Yes I am new, but I did already try up voting your answer. Stackoverflow came back with a notification that I am too new for my up votes to be displayed publicly (as my reputation is too low), but they did say that it will be counted. So I hope they also award you the deserving reputation score too :)

Comment: LOL. But you can (and should) always accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: I did not know that. I was waiting to get more answers. Anyway, I have marked it answered now.